# To make entire row mandatory to fill if one cell of that row is filled

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

For ms Excel 2007.
I want the user to fill all cells in a row IF any one cell of that row is filled.
I am using ms-Excel 2007.

Comment: What do you want it to do if they don't?  Throw an error or move back into the selected cell?

Comment: what do you mean by "fill" -- like the `Format.Fill` or like, filled with a non-null value?

Comment: Try `Worksheet_Change` Event to trap that. Give it a try and if you get stuck then simply post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: what you want is not really feasible in Excel...I guess you could try using the worksheet events to enforce a rule, but why? If you want to ensure no null values go in your table or database, then use a VBA Userform.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this is by using a form. The form would have to be the only way that the user can enter data (you protect the worksheet and the form code "unprotects" it), then when the user fills out the form you check the fields for errors (not just omissions, but things like "that is not a valid date", etc).

To see what I mean, you can see a form at work for data entry in [this tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/tp/090828-excel-data-entry-form-hub.htm). Maybe that's all you need, although there's not really solid data validation built in. But it will get you started.

Once you see how that works, you can try to design your own form that replicates the functionality of this one, but that includes error trapping. This involves opening the VBA editor (`<Alt-F11>`), inserting a user form, adding fields and buttons, and writing some code that is run when the "OK" button is clicked.

Not saying this is an easy thing to implement (I am guessing from the question that you may be new at this), but give it a shot. When you get stuck - post an update to your question or leave a comment.